# CHTML MathJax sf font

Tags: mathjax

I use solution for **SVG** and **HTML-CSS** from:
https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-docs/wiki/Can-MathJax-use-font-xxxx%3F

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  "HTML-CSS": {availableFonts: ["TeX"]},
         MMLorHTML: {prefer: "HTML"}
});
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("HTML-CSS Jax Ready",function () {
  var VARIANT = MathJax.OutputJax["HTML-CSS"].FONTDATA.VARIANT;
  VARIANT["normal"].fonts.unshift("MathJax_SansSerif");
  VARIANT["bold"].fonts.unshift("MathJax_SansSerif-bold");
  VARIANT["italic"].fonts.unshift("MathJax_SansSerif-italic");
  VARIANT["-tex-mathit"].fonts.unshift("MathJax_SansSerif-italic");
});
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("SVG Jax Ready",function () {
  var VARIANT = MathJax.OutputJax.SVG.FONTDATA.VARIANT;
  VARIANT["normal"].fonts.unshift("MathJax_SansSerif");
  VARIANT["bold"].fonts.unshift("MathJax_SansSerif-bold");
  VARIANT["italic"].fonts.unshift("MathJax_SansSerif-italic");
  VARIANT["-tex-mathit"].fonts.unshift("MathJax_SansSerif-italic");
});
```

Is there a way to do the same for **CHTML**? Since StartupHook signal "CommonHTML Jax Ready" doesn't work.

Comment: While *some* questions about MathJax can be on topic, this one has no connection whatsoever with TeX and friends. Sorry, but it's off topic.